# Debian (wheezy) force cache to RAM

Tags: memory, cache, debian-wheezy

I have Linux server running about 6 game servers. I have 3 GB total of RAM but I use only about 500 MB. Is there a way to cache one of my game servers (all the files - even not actually used maps etc. - about 1,5 GB) to RAM?

The reason I want to do this is because my Linux server is virtual and the hard drives ar very slow, so there is really big IO wait time.

IO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HLhB.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply read each file? That would put them in the cache, so long as nothing else needs that space after you 'read' them.

I think you can accomplish this by just `grep`ing each file that you want cached, or use it on the directory with the recursive option to cache every file in said directory.

Comment: thx, I found answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/43383/caching-preloading-files-on-linux-into-ram